# How does one access CSR challengePassword with pyca/cryptography?

Tags: python, cryptography, csr

I have created a CSR with the `challengePassword` attribute (oid `1.2.840.113549.1.9.7`) via `openssl` cli:

```
openssl req  -nodes -new -newkey rsa:4096 -out www.example.com.csr -keyout www.example.com.key
```

I verify that the `challengePassword` is present via

```
openssl req -noout -text -in www.example.com.csr
```

When I read it in with `cryptography.x509.load_pem_x509_csr()`, I can find no record of 'Attributes' or this specific oid, e.g.

```python
   csr = x509.load_pem_x509_csr(csr_data, default_backend())
   print(csr.subject) # Lists expected subject info; countryName, etc.
   CHALLENGE_OID = "1.2.840.113549.1.9.7"
   challenge_att = x509.oid.ObjectIdentifier(CHALLENGE_OID)
   challenge = csr.subject.get_attributes_for_oid(challenge_att) # challenge is []
```

Is this Attribute visible anywhere in the resulting object? The [pyca/cryptography docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-csr-certificate-signing-request-object) are not helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A challenge password is an attribute encoded into the CSR. Unfortunately, arbitrary attributes aren't currently supported by pyca/cryptography. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/3384) for this on GitHub right now but no one has implemented it yet.